# How to enforce a Collection (Seq, List etc.) to accept only positive integers - Scala

Tags: scala, compilation, integer, constraints

I would ideally like to enforce a Collection in Scala to allow only positive integers.  Is there way?

I can achieve it at run time by wrapping a Sequence in a class and verifying it's initialization, but that would mean handling exception at run time.  A compile time solution would be nicer.

Comment: The collection is a red herring. Start by defining a "positive integer" type, then have a regular collection of that.

Comment: +1 the comment above; though it is possible to use shapeless Nat types, but don't use it if you want only nats

Comment: Not sure what the collections have to do with this, but [spire](https://github.com/non/spire) contains types for positive fixed-size integers (UInt, ULong, ...) as well as positive arbitrary precision integers (Natural).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) to define a `List[Int @@ Positive]`, that is a list of `Int`s that are greater than zero. refined will then check at compile-time that all elements in your list are positive:

```
import eu.timepit.refined.auto._
import eu.timepit.refined.numeric.Positive
import shapeless.tag.@@

scala> val posInts: List[Int @@ Positive] = List(1, 2, 3)
posInts: List[Int @@ Positive] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

If you try to put a non-positive `Int` in the `List`, you'll get a compile error:

```
scala> val posInts: List[Int @@ Positive] = List(1, 2, 3, -4)
<console>:43: error: Predicate failed: (-4 > 0).
       val posInts: List[Int @@ Positive] = List(1, 2, 3, -4)
                                                           ^
```